# Trace of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Well, I was solving exercises and here is one I cant solve.

$tr(A^TA)tr(B^TB)\geq tr(A^TB)^2$

I have tried it and I come with proof that $tr(A^TA)>0$ I dont know how it helps.


Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1)You should show an attempt of  yours, 2) The square refers to the trace or to the matrix product?

Comment: @Eureka square refers to the trace

Comment: Do you know Cauchy Schwarz inequality?

Comment: @Eureka Yes I know

Comment: Well ,prove that $\langle A,B \rangle:=tr(A^T B)$ is a scalar product, and then this disequality is simply Cauchy Schwarz(the matrices are square right?)

Answer (score 0):

For any square or rectangular matrx $C,$  we find $$  \operatorname{trace} C^T C \geq 0$$
because it is simply the sum of the squares of all elements.

Next, for any square matrix $M$ we have
$$  \operatorname{trace} M^T =  \operatorname{trace} M$$
Detail, $$(G^T H )^T = H^T G $$

Finally,
$$   \operatorname{trace} \; (A-B)^T (A-B) \geq 0.    $$
Expand this, there is a factor of $2$ you are missing.